# Deleted actions appear again after export/import from Wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

When I export and import an app on Wit.ai, all the actions (responses) that I deleted before re-appear (and are marked as not unused). Is this intended? It's not what I would expect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not intended and most likely a bug. However I just tested the following scenario and it worked for me
Add a "test" Bot Sends to one of my story, Save it. Then remove it from a Story and Save the story again.
Went to the action tab, delete the action "test". Then export the app.
Create a new app by importing the exported one.
Checked in both the story and the actions tab and the "test" answer was not there